# % CHANGE IN NEGATIVE BASE

Tags: real-numbers, finance, percentages, ratio

I need to find correct formula to calculate percentage change from a negative base. Assume this is my company financials where

> Year-$1$ Profit: Negative $80$ Crore
>
> Year-$2$ Profit: Negative $125$ Crore, and
>
> Year-$3$ Profit: $200$ Crore.

Now evaluating Year-$3$ performance with Year-$2$ & Year-$1$ I get $350\%$ increase in Year-$3$ compared to Year-$1$ whereas I get $260\%$ increase in Year-$3$ as compared to Year-$2$ (taking the denominator as absolute base) But one fundamental error in it is that if we see absolute change it is more in Year-$3$ and year-$2$ comparison whereas actual $\%$ change shown is less. It is because of the larger base, in such a scenario what formula I should use to get a correct $\%$ change

Comment: Percentage changes often do not convey useful immediate information when starting from negative profits.  You might consider finding some other way of  conveying the information

Comment: See [Net Income](http://online.wsj.com/public/resources/documents/doe-help.htm).